# How to change time with moment.js?

Tags: javascript, date, typescript, time, momentjs

I want to change some time using moment.js.

I have next time: `Tue May 16 2017 15:34:23 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`,
and I want to change it to `11.11` for example.

And time should be `Tue May 16 2017 11:11:23 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)`.

How can i implement this?

Comment: You might start by [*parsing the string*](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/), with something like `moment(dateString, 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ')`.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

As stated by others in the comment, you have to:

1. Parse your input as moment object, you can use:

   - [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) if your input is a String
   - [`moment(Date)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/) if your input is a JavaScript Date
2. Use moment [setters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/) (e.g. [`set`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/)) to set both hours and minutes.

You can use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to display your moment object. If you need to convert moment object to JavaScript date you can use [`toDate()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) method.

Here live sample:

```js
var dateString = 'Tue May 16 2017 15:34:23 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)';
var m = moment(dateString, 'ddd MMM D YYYY HH:mm:ss ZZ');
// Use moment(Date) if your input is a JS Date
//var m = moment(date);
m.set({h: 11, m: 11});
console.log(m.format());
console.log(m.toDate().toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```