# Add hours to timestamp in moment.js

Tags: momentjs, angular7

I have two inputs first input is for getting the date and the second input is for getting the time of the day.

For example,

User selects date: 20 January 2019 and time: 12:30 pm.

When I convert the date input to Unix timestamp  I get the timestamp for 00:00 hours on 20 January 2019.

```
startingDate = moment(date.startsOn).unix();
```

So I want to add hours that I'm getting from the user into the date timestamp.

When I try to convert hours into Unix timestamp I get a timestamp for the present day along with the hours entered by the user i.e. I get timestamp for 12:00 pm on 11 January 2019.

```
startingTime = moment(date.startingTime).unix();
```

Any suggestion how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please, post some code...

Comment: Probably [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44001718/4131048) a similar issue, simply use momentjs [setters](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/set/) (or Date `setHours()`, `setMinutes()`)

Comment: Have you tried moment(date.startsOn).add(6, 'hours').unix()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do this in this way:
As I had my starting date and time in unix format

```
startingDate = moment(date.startsOn).unix();
startingTime = moment(date.startingTime).unix();
```

I had to convert them into moment format

```
const date = moment.unix(this.startingDate).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm a'); 
const hours = moment.unix(this.startingTime).format('HH');
```

Then I added hours to my date constant

```
var finalTime = date.add(hours, 'hours');
```

Then I posted this finalTime to my API.